# Oracle returns me oci_connect(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred in oracle 8g

Tags: php, oracle

during I`m trying to get data from oracle 8g, I get oci_connect(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout. When I am performing few queries everything is rightly, but if I am trying to get slightly much queries I get mentioned error. Interesting fact, if I am adding sleep(1) php function it resolves problem, but caused to take much time for.

```
Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred in C:\apache\Apache24\htdocs\statistic\src\OracleRequest.php on line 105

Fatal error: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred in C:\apache\Apache24\htdocs\statistic\src\OracleRequest.php on line 108
```

Queries are simple, here is for instance

```
public function getCountOfEntriesByEmployee($surname, $type_of_document)
{
    $conn = oci_connect("system", "manager", $this->dsn);
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    if($type_of_document == self::TYPE_OF_DOCUMENT["COMMON_INCOME"]) {
        $common_income_documents_by_employee = oci_parse($conn,
            "SELECT COUNT(num_card) FROM OFFICE_DOC_IN_CARDS
                     WHERE DCUS_CODE = 1
                     and YEAR_CARD = 2020
                     and TYPE_CARD = " . $type_of_document . "
                     and DATE_IN = to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                     and SHORT_CONTENT NOT LIKE '%test db%'      
                     and (
                     (CONCAT(SHORT_CONTENT, SHORT_CONTENT2) like " . "'%*" . mb_convert_encoding($surname, "CP1251") . "%')
                     or  
                     (CONCAT(SHORT_CONTENT, SHORT_CONTENT2) like " . "'% * " . mb_convert_encoding($surname, "CP1251") . "%')
                     )"
        );


        oci_execute($common_income_documents_by_employee);
        $data = oci_fetch_row($common_income_documents_by_employee)[0];
        oci_free_statement($common_income_documents_by_employee);
        oci_close($conn);
        return $data;
```

**Thanks a lot everyone!**

Comment: I don't know. This: `and DATE_IN = to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')` could and **should** be rewritten to `and DATE_IN = trunc(sysdate)` because there's no point in converting SYSDATE to string and back to DATE, just to remove its time component. BTW, Oracle 8i? Gosh! I thought it was long time dead. I'm kind of glad it is not.

Comment: Are you crazy??? Your code is a great invitation for SQL-Injection. `SYSTEM` is a high privileged DBA account and you use the default password! It is a miracle that your database has not been hacked yet (maybe it has been already). Oracle 8 is more than 20 years old. I wounder that you still find clients which are able to connect to it.

Comment: Guys, it's private network, it doesn't have access to the internet and YES it's legacy code))) P.S. The proccess of finding the client was TERRIBLE

Comment: There are many Oracle databases which are not public to the internet. But even at school I would not accept such code from students if I would be the teacher/trainer. When a developer gets used to write such dangerous code then he/she will do the same also in a "real" environment - I speak from experience and have seen it!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a PHP issue - issue is result of slow network or other Network related issues. please try to use

```
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT
SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT
SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT
```

Inside

```
$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
```

on Oracle Client used by PHP

[https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/sqlnet.htm#:~:text=INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT&text=Use%20the%20SQLNET.,provide%20the%20necessary%20authentication%20information](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/sqlnet.htm#:%7E:text=INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT&text=Use%20the%20SQLNET.,provide%20the%20necessary%20authentication%20information).

Comment: I have been trying to assign different values into those params but it had not changed the situation. Problem is still existing

Comment: And why does sleep() php function solve this problem If it`s a network problem

Comment: ORA-12170 ist propagated from Transparent Network substrate (TNS) to Oracle client library function. Example: PHP. PHP used OCI calls (Oracle Call Interface - the C-API. From OCI wents down UPI - User Program Interface - then TNS (today "Oracle Network" ) - OS network calls - OSI stack - NIC ..... and then to NIC of server and up to DB process (I Dont list the stack). What you can try is to do a network trace - will Post in Next comment...

Comment: Please try to perform network trace http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_net_tracing.htm and search for 12170 in trace

Comment: I switched on the logging and tracing but any files don`t appear in the particular directory. When I connected to oracle through desktop application (very old application was written maybe on delphi) tracing files appeared but still have not beenappearing when I am connecting through php

Comment: You have to ensure that System variables exist. If your Client for example in c:\oracle\client11g  then ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\client11g PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;<other path entries> TNS_ADMIN=%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin After that Edit %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin\sqlnet.ora und add DIAG_ADR_ENABLED = OFF as first entry - traces should written when c:\temp exist and following set in sqlnet.ora 
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = 16
TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT = c:\temp after that boot  Client and retry

Comment: nladtrm: exit;
nscall: error exit;
nioqper:  error from nscall;
nioqper:    ns main err code: 12535;
nioqper:    ns (2)  err code: 12560;
nioqper:    nt main err code: 505;
nioqper:    nt (2)  err code: 60;
nioqper:    nt OS   err code: 0;
niomapnserror: entry;
niqme: entry;
niqme: reporting NS-12535 error as ORA-12535;
niqme: exit;
niomapnserror: exit;
niotns: Couldn't connect, returning 12170;
nioqer: entry;
nioqer:  incoming err = 12170;
nioqce: entry;
nioqce: exit;
nioqer:  returning err = 3113;

Comment: What exactly Database release and Client release you are using ? Please note that it is only supported to connect with Oracle client 10g  (10.X) or lower to DB 8i (8.1.X)

Comment: I am using DBMS: Oracle (ver. Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.0.0, Driver: Oracle JDBC driver (ver. 10.2.0.1.0, JDBC10.2)

Comment: You can download the Instant Client 10.2.0.5 for Windows 64bit (W7 should work - W10 maybe) for free from OTN - https://www.oracle.com/de/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html#license-lightbox and JDBC. 10.2.0.1 is shaky and not very stable.

Comment: I downloaded and installed it, it didn't change anything